# RxSwift: How to pass a control event through multiple view models

Tags: mvvm, rx-swift, reactivex

I have a collection view cell with a button, and I want to pass the tap control event (`button.rx.rap`) through the cell's view model, through the view controller's view model and to the collection view controller itself (as I need to present a view controller on tap event).

How can this be achieved in a Rx way (ideally without using subjects)?

Answer (score 0):

The way we do it is by using a PublishSubject in the viewmodel.
For example

```
class CellViewModel {

   let optionButtons: [TripOptionButtonsCellView.TripOptionButtonType]
   let optionButtonTapped = PublishSubject<TripOptionButtonsCellView.TripOptionButtonAction>()

   init()

      ...                
   }

   func switchButtonValueChanged( to isOn: Bool ) {

       viewModel?.optionButtonTapped.onNext(.enableOrDisableNotifications(isEnabled: isOn))

  }

}
```

You can then listen to the next event in your view controller and pass that on to wherever you want. You just have to make sure you resubscribe because you tableviewcells can be recycled.